# Can anyone help me understand Route 53 in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have just registered an aws server (free tire) and 2-3 days back added the domain name through route and now I can see 0.60$ in my bill.

Can anyone tell me why is that and what does this mean:-

**$0.40 per 1,000,000 queries for the first 1 Billion queries
1,086.000 Queries**

**$0.50 per Hosted Zone for the first 25 Hosted Zones
1.000 HostedZone**

I have no idea what does this mean, Is there a way to stop this billing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are related to your DNS configuration, ultimately by purchasing a Route 53 domain you default to using Route 53 as a DNS management service.

**0.40 per 1,000,000 queries for the first 1 Billion queries 1,086.000 Queries**

This is based on the number of DNS queries that are performed to lookup a record for your domain. For example if your website (`example.com`) is attempted to be accessed by a client who has either not been to your website or the cached value has expired, then a query will be performed against the hosted zone for `example.com`.

**0.50 per Hosted Zone for the first 25 Hosted Zones 1.000 HostedZone**

This is a flat fee for having a hosted zone within Route 53, the Hosted Zone is responsible for storing all DNS records for a specific domain. Without this you would not currently have any DNS support for your domain as no records would exist.

Comment: is there a way to stop that query thing and what sort of records is it storing for the specific domain

Comment: and can I see the list of queries ?

Comment: You can enable Route 53 logging (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-monitoring.html) although it comes at a cost. The records it stores are for resolving your domains and the services it uses. If you open Route 53 and go to hosted zones you can click on your domain to see the records that exist. If you are not using the domain you can delete the public hosted zone however any records will no longer resolve (i.e. website names)